# CentOS - resize2fs error operation not permitted while trying to add group #

Tags: centos

I am working on EC2 instance on AWS.

OS is CentOS 6.5 and paravirtualized.

When I started instance, I enter SSD storage as 32GB.

But in instance, only 8GB is mounted.

So I expand block on `/dev/xvda` (which was mounted on `/@) from 8GB to 32GB.

And I tried to run command `resize2fs /dev/xdva1` but got error like below:

```
Filesystem at /dev/xvda1 is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old desc_blocks = 1, new_desc_blocks = 2
Performing an on-line resize of /dev/xvda1 to 8388352 (4k) blocks.
resize2fs: Operation not permitted While trying to add group #81
```

And System Error on AWS management console:

```
EXT4-fs warning (device xvda1): ext4_group_add:1605: No reserved GDT blocks, can't resize
EXT4-fs warning (device xvda1): ext4_group_add:1605: No reserved GDT blocks, can't resize
EXT4-fs warning (device xvda1): ext4_group_add:1605: No reserved GDT blocks, can't resize
EXT4-fs warning (device xvda1): ext4_group_add:1605: No reserved GDT blocks, can't resize
EXT4-fs warning (device xvda1): ext4_group_add:1605: No reserved GDT blocks, can't resize
```

Here are current status

- `df -h`

  [image: df -h]
- `lsblk`

  [image: lsblk]

I want `/dev/xvda1` to increase to 32GB or newly make `/dev/xvda2` as remain disk.

How can I make it?

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this is that when you create a new file system - certain file system structures are reserved for a possible file system expansion later on (inodes, block bitmaps).
Those structures are stored in so called GDT - Group Descriptor Table.
So what happened - when your original file system was created amount of reserved structures was not enough for extending this file system to 32GB.
Try to expand it to a smaller size - let's say 16GB (so you would have to resize your partition once again to a smaller size.
If you must have 32GB - you can't expand it online. You would have to backup your data and resize offline.
What type of root disk is your instance running?

1. Is it instance-store
   or
2. EBS

Cause depending on which one it is - your file system expansion strategy will be different.

Take a look at these docs:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/RootDeviceStorage.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/best-practices-storage.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html

Answer (score 1):

In AWS management console, I stopped ec2 instance and detached volume.

I attached other instance not as boot device, and run fsck, resize2fs.

It worked because I run these command in off-line and not mounted.